# how to make c# window form of AutoCAD plugin and AutoCAD itself available simultaneously

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin

I have created a basic plugin for AutoCAD. In my plugin some task is being done through c# windows form. My end user require to access autocad while windows form is open. Currently AutoCAD is being un-accessible if c# windows form is open. To use AutoCAD user has to close form first.

Is there a way to make both the autocad and windows form accessible simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a modeless form:

```
Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.ShowModelessDialog
```

But it's not very intuitive, I would suggest a PaletteSet that hosts a user control.

```
Autodesk.AutoCAD.Windows.PaletteSet ps; // declare as a STATIC variable, avoid duplicate
ps.Add("Name here", userCtrl);
ps.Visible = true;
```

I prefer the Modal way and, inside a button where you need the user to select something on the drawing, use a EditorUserInteraction object

```
Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
using (EditorUserInteraction userIt = ed.StartUserInteraction())
{
  // this will close the form and go to the model space, once finished, the form gets back
}
```